# failed to crawl youtube video title name

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I tried to crawl this all video title name, but didn't get results, and bob up a bunch of errors, is there someone can tell me which parts I made is wrong

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import  operator

def start(url):
    word_list = []
    source_code = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code,"html.parser")
    for post_text in soup.findAll('a',{'class':'yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-grid-video- 
 renderer'}): 
 
        content = post_text.string
        words = content.lower().split()
        for each_word in words:
            print(each_word)
            word_list.append(each_word)

start('https://www.youtube.com/c/DolceVitaChannel/videos')
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some issues in your code and tried again with a header but didn't work. So I decided to use selenium. However, it worked. Here is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
#firefox_options.add_argument('--headless') # uncomment to use headless mode

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver', firefox_options=firefox_options)

def start(url):
    word_list = []
    driver.get(url)
    for post_text in driver.find_elements_by_id('video-title'): 
        content = post_text.text
        words = content.lower().split()
        for each_word in words:
            print(each_word)
            word_list.append(each_word)

start('https://www.youtube.com/c/DolceVitaChannel/videos')
driver.close()
```

Comment: looks like a set of functions instead of beautifulsoup and request something ,but why was this beautifulsoup and request can't work ,is that webpage have some firewall or something ?

Comment: As I know It is because of  JS

Answer (score 0):

When you want to crawl on a site like youtube or instagram, you have a problem with javascript code, which requires you to be on the site at the same time with a browser to crawl what you want.

But the solutions are:

1 - In these cases, you can go to your browser's network section and check the requests that are sent to the server and look for the response you want (in this case, I did not find what I was looking for).

2 - If youtube gives you the API you want, you can use it or you can search for a simpler way and look for a python package that can work with youtube api, such as steam library [You can search because python just doesn't have a library to revive a dead person :))]

3 - and My favorite solution is to use the powerful selenium framework. You can both open your browser and do so with the headless ability without opening your browser.

You can use the following code, which is a combination of selenium framework and beautifulsoup library

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver_path = r'geckodriver path'

firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_path, firefox_options=firefox_options)

def start(url):
    titles_list = []
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
    posts_div = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'style-scope ytd-grid-renderer'})

    posts = posts_div[0].find_all("ytd-grid-video-renderer")

    for post in posts:
        details = post.find("div", attrs={"id": "details"})
        post_title = details.find("a").text
        titles_list.append(post_title)
    return titles_list


words = start('https://www.youtube.com/c/DolceVitaChannel/videos')
driver.close()


print("\n\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n\n")

for word in words:
    print(word)
```

Comment: thank you for response ,actually i didn't learn java ever, generally just i need to write some java code to fix it ,is that point ?  and what's meaning of that headless...

Comment: The right way to say that you can say js and not say java because they are different and that you don't need to know how to use js code just you can use solutions i said
And that headless is name of option in selenium for when you want your crawler to run faster and you don't need to open your system browser by the driver and perform the desired operation.